# How can I define a composite key in serverless.yml for DynamoDB?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, serverless-framework

I am trying to define a dynamodb table that has a 3 column composite key. Is this possible?

I've seen examples and tutorials that have code like this:

```
resources:
  Resources:
    TodosDynamoDbTable:
      Type: 'AWS::DynamoDB::Table'
      DeletionPolicy: Retain
      Properties:
        AttributeDefinitions:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            AttributeType: S
        KeySchema:
          -
            AttributeName: id
            KeyType: HASH
        ProvisionedThroughput:
          ReadCapacityUnits: 1
          WriteCapacityUnits: 1
        TableName: ${self:provider.environment.DYNAMODB_TABLE}
```

But that only has a single column and a single key. My table looks like this:

```
  Properties:
    AttributeDefinitions:
      - AttributeName: id
        AttributeType: N
      - AttributeName: server
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: room
        AttributeType: S
      - AttributeName: friendlyName
        AttributeType: S
```

I want a key on `id`, `server` and `room`. A user can be in multiple rooms on the same server and in multiple rooms on multiple servers. But, across the three keys, it will always be unique.

I don't know how to define the `KeySchema` part. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

First of all you cannot create a composite key (as in relational databases) in DynamoDB.

The keys you get in a table are Hash and Range (Also called Sort and optional) keys. Since this limits the querying capability, DynamoDB supports creating indexes called Global Secondary Index(GSI) and Local Secondary Index (LSI) to extend the query capabilities.

Based on your schema, since the combination of id, server and room are unique, you can use a concatenation for the Hash key such as `id_server_room` so that the items in the table are enforced for uniqueness.

You can then create id, server and room as attributes. To enable querying from those attributes efficiently, create GSIs as required.